# Powershell, fail to load SqlCredential

Tags: .net, sql-server, powershell

I am new to PowerShell and I am trying a simple script that executes a SQL query.  It works fine on my Windows 8 machine (PS 3.0), but not on the client machine (2008R2, PS 2.0) - I am getting an exception on this line:

```
$credentials = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential -argumentlist $user, $password

New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

Both machines have .NET 2.0-4.0  installed.

Any advice on how to debug and fix this would be appreciated.

Also, how can I know what assembly file / dll defines a given type? For example, how do I find the full path to the DLL that contains `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential` (I do not see a `System.Data.SqlClient` in the GAC on my Windows 8 machine, but it works there...)?

Thanks!

Comment: same issue but in Mac OSX. Is there a way to load it for .Net Core 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You're saying the machines have .NET 2.0-4.0 installed. However, the class `SqlCredential` has been introduced in .NET 4.5:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/03/09/safer-passwords-with-sqlcredential.aspx

Maybe that is the issue then? Maybe the Win8 has it installed?

Comment: Interesting.  .NET 4.5 does not show up under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework, but I guess it is default with Windows 8 and maybe lives elsewhere...  So I guess that leaves me with no simple way of using secure connection strings from Powershell, unless I also install .NET 4.5?

Comment: @JimBalo - .NET 4.5 overrides the framework dlls in 4.0 directory, so unless you're looking specifically at the contents you won't notice a difference. See this article for details: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can just download .Net 4.5.  I believe that will fix your problems.
   In my present job, I can't upgrade .Net because I am writing Powershell scripts that run remotely on servers, some of which may not have the latest version of .Net.  For example, I can't use System.Data.sqlclient.SqlQuery, because, even though most of the System.Data.SqlClient assembly is loaded, the class for System.Data.sqlclient.SqlQuery is not part of that assembly.  Too bad, because many of the example scripts for using DataAdapter reference the .SQLQuery class, which is in .Net 4.5 .